# Bootstrap 3 dropdown refuses to work in rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Am using the bootstrap-sass 3.1.1 gem in a rails 4 application. The css works fine but I cant get the dropdown to appear at all. My application.js file is like so.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I also added this line to the `config\application.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

My gemfile looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1'

group :development,:test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Here is my view code

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
Choose a Specialty
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">General Practioner</a>  </li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Dentist</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Dermatologist</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Eye Doctor</a></li>
</ul>
```

I cant figure out what's wrong? any clues?

Comment: You should show your view code

Answer (score 1):

In order to activate dropdowns you should add this to your application.js

```
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
```

same for other js components. You can read it [here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#javascript](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#javascript)

This is my complete application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap/affix
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
//= require bootstrap/carousel
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/tab
//= require bootstrap/transition
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/tooltip
//= require bootstrap/popover
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

To better help you with bootstrap, i would also add

`bootstrap-sass-extras`

in your gemfile https://github.com/doabit/bootstrap-sass-extras

Comment: perfect, I only added the "bootstrap-sass-extras" gem and the //= require bootstrap and it fixed the problem, are the others neccesary? I think with just that line it enables all the components.....

Comment: I just tried adding a carousel without using that line  
//= require bootstrap/carousel and it works perfectly.....so I guess that you only need //= require bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a bootstrap theme. I have them in vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css
In application.js add the following.
And just get a copy of bootstrap.js and put it in assets/javascripts folder

```
//= require bootstrap
```

And in application.css make sure you have

```
*= require "bootstrap.min.css"
```